# Javascript object function as parameter in an other object

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

How can I pass a object function as a parameter in an other Object like the following Example?

```
function Page(name) { this.name = name;}
Page.prototype.functionA = function(callback){
    callback(null,'I am A');
}
Page.prototype.functionB = function(callback){
    callback(null,'I am B');
}

function Sitemap() { this.children = [];}
Sitemap.prototype.getPages = function(){
    return this.children;
}
Sitemap.prototype.updateSiteMap = function (Page.functionX, done){
   var pages = this.getPages();
   var update = function(page, cb) {
       page.functionX(function () {
            cb(null);
       });
   };
   async.map(pages, update, function(err, result){
      done(null, result);
   });
};
```

I want to decide which function to call on the Object by a condition

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Emmm... something like that?

```
Sitemap.prototype.updateSiteMap = function (functionName, done){
   var pages = this.getPages();
   var update = function(page, cb) {
       page[functionName](function () {
            cb(null);
       });
   };
   ...
};

// Usage

...updateSiteMap('functionA', done);
```

Comment: i found a way to run it, see response
Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I could run it using `static` function in the`Class Page` and `.call()` on the given function:

```
function Page(name) { this.name = name;}
Page.functionA = function(callback){
     callback(null,'I am A');
}
Page.functionB = function(callback){
     callback(null,'I am B');
}

function Sitemap() { this.children = [];}
Sitemap.prototype.getPages = function(){
   return this.children;
}
Sitemap.prototype.updateSiteMap = function (functionX, done){
   var pages = this.getPages();
   var update = function(page, cb) {
      functionX.call(page, function () {
          cb(null);
      });
   };
   async.map(pages, update, function(err, result){
      done(null, result);
   });
};
```

thank you anyway